# Kubunu 17 Calendar Language

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, date

I have all my language set to British English but the calendar on the login splash and on the desktop panel shows in French. Very mysterious. What do I need to set to get this in English?

Comment: The system language and locale ("Regional Formats") are independent.

Comment: So any idea how I get the calendar in English?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you've already worked this out quite a while ago. However, for anyone else looking.

Go into System settings > regional settings > formats and check 'detailed settings'. Then you'll be able to change all of that to your preferred laguage.